# why do I get the monitoring information from curl in some case and not in other case?

Tags: cron, curl

When I run the following command in an interactive bash shell:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/ip
123.45.67.890
```

If I create `/etc/cron.d/myjob`:

```
24 * * * * tim ( date && curl ipinfo.io/ip && date ) > /tmp/cron.log 2>&1
```

in /tmp/cron.log, I will get the following monitoring information from curl:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0^M100    14  100    14    0     0    147      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   148
123.45.67.890
```

why do I get the  monitoring information from curl in some case and not in other case? What are the two kinds of cases? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the first case you’re writing to a terminal; [the `curl` manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#PROGRESS) says of its progress meter that

> curl displays this data to the terminal by default, so if you invoke curl to do an operation and it is about to write data to the terminal, it *disables* the progress meter as otherwise it would mess up the output mixing progress meter and response data.

When the progress meter isn’t disabled `curl` outputs it to standard error, and the downloaded data to standard input; in your cron job, neither of these are a terminal, and they are both redirected to `/tmp/cron.log`, so you see both in the log file.

This behaviour means `curl` “behaves nicely” in common usage scenarios. If you use `curl` to retrieve data and output it to the terminal, as in your first example, all you see is the data. If you use `curl` to retrieve data and output it to a file, or a pipe, you see progress information in the terminal.

In you cron job, you’re mixing up the two with your dual redirection to `/tmp/cron.log`. If you don’t want to see the output mixed up, you can disable the progress meter entirely with the `-s` option, or redirect standard error to another file:

```
24 * * * * tim ( date && curl -s ipinfo.io/ip && date ) > /tmp/cron.log 2>&1
```

or

```
24 * * * * tim ( date && curl ipinfo.io/ip && date ) > /tmp/cron.log 2>/tmp/cron.err
```

Comment: Thanks. Why would cron behave differently when writes to terminal or a file? In a file, it still mess up the output mixing progress meter and response data.

Comment: cron isn’t behaving differently, `curl` is. And you’re the one arranging for output to go to the same file! If you don’t want progress information, disable it (`-s`) or redirect errors to another file.